# A schedule is not conflict-serializable. Is it serializable?

Tags: concurrency, database-theory, databases

While reading [this](http://discovery.csc.ncsu.edu/Courses/csc440-S08/Quiz-4-ConcurrencyControl.pdf) solved quiz on concurrency control, I got stuck on exercise 2, which reads as follows:

> 2) Consider the following schedule:
>
> S: r1(X), w2(X), r3(X), r1(Y), w2(Z), r3(Y), w3(Z), w1(Y)
>
> (a) (2 points) Draw the precedence graph.
>
> [image]
>
> (b) (1 point) Is S conflict serializable?
>
> No.

After reading that S is not conflict-serializable, my question is: can we say that S is serializable? Any suggestions?

Thanks to anyone who help me.

Comment: Please include all necessary material in the question. People shouldn't have to follow a link to find out what you're even asking.

Answer (score 1):

A schedule is considered serializable if it is equivalent to a serial one. The conflict graph that appears on the answer to item (a) is proof that the schedule is not conflict-serializable, and it is also not *view-serializable*, because there is still a cycle between $T_1$ and $T_3$, when considering just the history of the data they visualize. That means the schedule cannot be considered serializable at all.

Conflict-serializability is stronger than view-serializability. It is the criterion used for the implementation of most schedulers, and that is why the quiz emphasizes this point.